# Openlayers WMTS custom configuration problem

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to use WMTS layers in opnelayers project. This is my firt time when I try to use WMTS instead of WMS. Unfortunatelly I am stuck. I have no idea how to set up.

PLease help me to set up correct settings:

[WMTS url GetCapabilities](https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/HighResolution?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)

my code (I used template from example on opnelayers.org):

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import WMTS from 'ol/source/WMTS.js';
import WMTSTileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/WMTS.js';
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj.js';
import {getTopLeft, getWidth} from 'ol/extent.js';

const projection = getProjection('EPSG:4326');
const projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
const size = getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
const resolutions = new Array(19);
const matrixIds = new Array(19);
for (let z = 0; z < 19; ++z) {
  // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
  resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
  matrixIds[z] = z;
}

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    new TileLayer({
      opacity: 0.7,
      source: new WMTS({
        url: 'https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/HighResolution?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities',
        layer: 'ORTOFOTOMAPA',
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:2180',
        format: 'image/png',
        projection: projection,
        tileGrid: new WMTSTileGrid({
          origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
          resolutions: resolutions,
          matrixIds: matrixIds,
        }),
        // style: 'default',
        wrapX: true,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [2008582, 6753697],
    zoom: 7,
  }),
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom projection there will also be a custom tile grid, so it is easier to parse the capabilities and let OpenLayers obtain the options.  You will also need to define and register the EPSG:2180 projection (including the N-E axis order) using proj4.

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View, {createRotationConstraint} from 'ol/View.js';
import WMTS, {optionsFromCapabilities} from 'ol/source/WMTS.js';
import WMTSCapabilities from 'ol/format/WMTSCapabilities.js';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4';

proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:2180',
  '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs +axis=neu'
);
register(proj4);

const wmtsLayer = new TileLayer({
  opacity: 0.7,
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    wmtsLayer,
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [2008582, 6753697],
    zoom: 7,
  }),
});

const parser = new WMTSCapabilities();
fetch(
  'https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/HighResolution?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities'
)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function (text) {
    const result = parser.read(text);
    const options = optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
      layer: 'ORTOFOTOMAPA',
      matrixSet: 'EPSG:2180',
    });
    wmtsLayer.setSource(new WMTS(options));
  });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wmts-layer-from-capabilities-forked-6gu26y?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks Mike! If I would like to add this WMTS layer to my project, where I have my map and other layers what should I do? I code above the "map" is inside function.  How to combine them together?

Comment: You can define the layer without a source, add it to the map, then set the source asynchronously.  I have updated the answer.